# Which 240 volt circuits must (or should) have a neutral in new construction?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I wasn't able to find a complete list compiled online, so hopefully someone can help identify which 240 volt circuits are required by code to have 4 conductors run to them.

NEC 2014 applies here, but NEC 2017 will be adopted by my state in a few months.

This is my list, and best effort based on what I've been able to find:

1. Clothes Dryer - Neutral Required by code
2. Electric Range - Neutral Required by code
3. Well Pump - Not Required or useful
4. Air Handler w/ electric heat - Not Required or useful
5. AC Compressor - Not Required or useful
6. Hot Water Heater - Not Required or useful

Is this correct? Is there anything 240 besides a dryer and range that needs or would benefit from a neutral/ four conductor wire?

Comment: Looks good to me , some AC units need need neutral. And you will need a 120 outlet. For the AC unit or within site.

Comment: I am curious as to what Code article and section(s) requires the neutral on a range or dryer circuit? Does anyone have those?

Answer (score 1):

### Probably not, but check the nameplates to be sure, and a neutral can be a good idea anyhow

For a dedicated circuit, the power requirements are determined not by any paragraph in Code (it's legit to have a 240V-only dryer or range/oven circuit if said appliances don't need 120V, or not have circuits for a dryer or range if they run on gas), but by the *nameplate on the appliance the circuit feeds*.  So, you need to check the specs on what you're putting in to be certain you're running the correct circuits for them.

However, for the common-cases of the appliances you listed, you're likely to be correct -- electric dryers and ranges generally require 120V for lamps, controls, and the drum drive on a dryer while running the heater from 240V, while the rest of the appliances in question run their controls either directly from 240V or from a Class 2 control transformer, and all the motors in them are 240V as well.  Granted, running a neutral alongside the 240V may be a good idea, even if the appliance doesn't use it, so that 120V receptacles and luminaires can be provisioned for service purposes -- this is particularly important for the well pump and compressor/outdoor unit, but may be wise for the hot water heater as well.

(P.S. the trick with the neutral is to replace the normal disconnect box with something like an 8 or 12 slot subpanel -- this lets you have circuits for lights, service receptacles, and the like to go with your well pump, compressor, or whathaveyou without having to pull a zillion wires out that way.)